# How to have label on the same line as the textbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a form, where on the leftside are labels and on the right are textboxes, like it is on the picture:

[image]

Blue lines show that there are two columns and two rows inside a grid. The first row is ok. But in the second, where is also the "textbox description", the label on the leftside should be a few pixels up so it is on the same line as is the text in appropriate textbox.

How can I do it?

I've thought that I could place the description on a new grid row, but I don't like that idea. Is there any other, better solution?

Thanks

Comment: you can do like this <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox Text="Name"  />
            <Label   Content="{Binding ProductName}" />
        </StackPanel>

Comment: You need to move the textbox description to a new grid row in order to get that label positioned "correctly" (it is correct now, but the description is making the current row height slightly bigger). It sounds like a hack, but it isn't - positioning is exactly what grids were intended for.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<Some control>.Margin = new Thickness(0,-N,0,0);
```

where N is whatever amount you want for the TOP margin ... and yes, it's negative, meaning it will move the control UP